# Will the new Part 23 changes reduce the cost of avionics for existing aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, avionics

Will the part 23 changes coming in August help to reduce the cost of IFR GPS avionics? I'm looking to upgrade the IFR avionics in a 1978 Cessna 182.

Comment: Part 23 rewrite is mostly for the performance based certification standards on aircraft. This may have some effect on avionics, but if you are flying around in a certified airframe you'll need TSO'd avionics. It may help bring prices down a little bit, but the $1000 or so you might save on "cheap" avionics is, in my opinion, not worth the savings over name-brand stuff from Garmin.

Comment: @RonBeyer You can buy the same G5 from Garmin for experimental aircraft for $1,000 less than certificated aircraft. And the reason we have the G5 is because "cheap" avionics Dynon proved that the technology works in experimental aircraft and the FAA was persuaded to TSO it. A performance based standard is long overdue for avionics, and the FAA is taking baby steps toward that goal.

Comment: @JScarry The TSO/Non-TSO isn't going to change. Not saying that a performance based standard isn't where we should be.

Comment: a link to the "new part 23 changes" would help in making this question a bit more specific and not mixing it up next time there will be changes.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not: the purpose of the part 23 rewrite is to make it easier to certify a new *aircraft type* (not individual avionics or other systems) and it doesn't apply to existing aircraft. AOPA has [a good overview](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/advocacy-briefs/understanding-part-23-rewrite), including this (emphasis in the original):

> **10. Are the performance-based standards applicable to all aircraft?**
>
> No.  The new process of using performance-based standards is limited
>   to *new* airplanes certified under Part 23, which would include
>   airplanes with a maximum passenger-seating configuration of 19 or
>   less, and a maximum certificated takeoff weight of 19,000 pounds or
>   less.

To address the cost point directly, in theory if the part 23 rewrite creates additional demand for new aircraft, and if those aircraft use avionics that can also be retrofitted to existing aircraft, then the increased demand might reduce prices. But that's highly speculative.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the answer is a qualified 'yes.'  The revised rules do not modify the need for type certificates nor does it affect the certificates of any existing certificated aircraft.  So the major benefit will be when attempting to certificate a new aircraft design.

But the new rules can be applied to a modification to an existing type certificate.  In fact the FAA normally insists that when you make a major modification to an existing design, the changes must be compliant with the current rules.  This has historically been a burden because the rules kept getting tighter as time went along.

With the revised Part 23, the new rules can be used as the certification basis for an STC to an aircraft.  The primary issue is that this isn't a cheap process regardless of the underlying certification basis. But [EAA](http://www.eaa.org) has been working to obtain STCs that can be used just for this purpose.  In fact, they were able to obtain an STC for the installation of Dynon EFIS-D10A or EFIS-D100 as replacement for the primary attitude indicator. It should be pointed out that the Dynon equipment does not have a TSO or a PMA, but is  verified against the recently developed ASTM 3153-15, Standard Specification for Verification of Avionics Systems.

EAA's STC has an approved model list.   [From EAA's site:](https://www.eaa.org/en/eaa/aviation-communities-and-interests/pilot-resources/eaa-stc-low-cost-avionics)

> Currently, the Approved Model List (AML) includes the following
>   aircraft series (including all variants on each type certificate):
>
> Beechcraft Bonanza/Debonair, Beechcraft Musketeer/Sundowner/Sierra,
>   Beechcraft Skipper
>
> Cessna 150, Cessna 152, Cessna 170 Cessna 172, Cessna 175, Cessna 177,
>   Cessna 177RG, Cessna 180/185, Cessna 182, Cessna 205/206/207, Cessna
>   210
>
> Grumman AA-1/AA-5
>
> Maule M-4/5/6/7
>
> Mooney M20
>
> Piper PA-24, Piper PA-28, Piper PA-32, Piper PA-38

EAA members can purchase the STC from EAA for $100, allowing the Dynon equipment to be installed in any of the AML aircraft types.

Hopefully the use of this type of a process will expand and provide for more options at lower price points than in the past.  While it isn't a panacea, it will help.